# Print out favicon instead of link to it

Tags: php

I'm trying to print a website's favicon, as an image, not as a link to it.
I have a php script in which I extract the favicon, but now I want to show it as it is.
Here is what I've tried.

```
//extract favicon
$url = $_POST['url'];
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->strictErrorChecking = FALSE;
$doc->loadHTML(file_get_contents($url));
$xml = simplexml_import_dom($doc);
$arr = $xml->xpath('//link[@rel="shortcut icon"]');
echo "<br>";
//echo "favicon:";
if( $arr)
{
  $src = $arr[0]['href'];
  echo "<img src = "$src">";//as I can see, the parameter here cannot be a variable
  //second thing that I've tried: echo "<img src = "$arr[0]['href']""; it doesn't work either
}
```

This is what my script is echoing right now. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wkoyj.jpg

Instead of the link to the favicon, I want the actual favicon to be displayed. I hope I explained myself correctly.

Comment: Favicons are `.ico` . `<img>` tags won't work AFAIK. You have to convert them to image then output it. **Maybe** you can convert it to base64 and then output as an image but i am not sure...

Comment: @jgabriel No, it works fine

Comment: *"as I can see, the parameter here cannot be a variable"* - what does that mean? What's the *HTML* that this outputs exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is with the code:

```
echo "<img src = "$src">";//as I can see, the parameter here cannot be a variable
```

It should be

```
echo '<img src="'.$src.'">';
```

Or even

```
echo "<img src=\"$src\">";
```

Comment: Your problem was the use of quotes + the whitespaces